# She hops down to the rushes

Tags: phrase-meaning

> ‘Come down! I'll do that. I'll send a wagon after Mistress Stafford.
>   She can't carry all she owns.’ ‘I can do it. Master Secretary doesn't
>   deal with bed hangings.’ ‘Master Secretary deals with everything. I'm
>   surprised I don't make the king's shirts.’ Jane sways gently above
>   him. Her feet sink into the feathers. ‘Queen Katherine does. Still.’
>   ‘The Dowager Katherine. Come down.’ She hops down **to the rushes**,
>   giving her skirts a shake. ‘Even now after all that has passed between
>   them. She sent a new parcel last week.’
>
> — Wolf Hall by Hilary Mantel

What does "to the rushes" mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This *rushes* refers to **[rushes on the floor](http://www.sarahwoodbury.com/rushes-on-the-floor/)**. ***She hops down to the rushes*** means she hops down to the floor, which is covered with rushes.

> **[rush](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/rush_2#rush_2__10)**: a tall plant that looks like grass and grows in water. It is used for making baskets and covering floors. (Macmillan Dictionary)

---

The practice of covering floors with rushes in the Medieval times is mentioned on [Medieval Hygiene](http://www.medieval-life-and-times.info/medieval-life/medieval-hygiene.htm):

> #### Threat to Medieval Hygiene - Rush Flooring
>
> The practice of covering floors with rushes was a a real threat to hygiene and health during the Medieval times. Following the Black Death a limited number of carpets and mats were introduced to replace the floor rushes but floors strewn with straw or rushes were still favoured. Sweet smelling herbs such as lavender, camomile, rose petals, daisies and fennel were added to disguise the bad smells which were prevalent due to the inadequate plumbing systems and the rushes.

---

See also:

- [In a Song of Ice and Fire, what are rushes?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36967/in-a-song-of-ice-and-fire-what-are-rushes) - Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange
- [Notes on Medieval Life](http://historicalnovelists.tripod.com/medlife.htm)
- [Rushbearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rushbearing) (Wikipedia)

Comment: "The curtains were half drawn, the floor was swept  / 
    **[And strewn with rushes](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/180847)**, rosemary and may /
Lay thick upon the bed on which I lay, / 
Where through the lattice ivy-shadows crept."

Comment: @CopperKettle That's a nice poem! (though it's sad.) Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Rushes look like this:
[image: Rushes]

At the time when Wolf Hall is set, rushes were commonly used as a floor covering.  They were strewn across the wooden, stone or earth floor to provide insulation and a soft walking surface in the same way as we use carpets now.  So 'to the rushes' means 'to the floor'.

Comment: I hate it when I have to pick only one out of other equally helpful answers. Thank you.